# SQL using group by to have first row and count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x | x |
| 1 | x | y |
| 2 | y | z |

Now I want to group it by column `a` and have the first row of `b` and count of grouped items.
So the expected result would be:

| a | b | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x | 2 |
| 2 | y | 1 |

I know that I can do them in 2 separate queries but I cannot write them in a single query.

Comment: In the example, the value of `b` doesn't change for a single value of `a`, is this always true? If not, how do you know what is the "first" value? Is it ordered by the value of `c`?

Comment: yes assuming `b` always matches with `a`

Comment: Then there is no "first" value, they're all the same. Just take the `MIN`/`MAX`.

Comment: does min/max work with text?

Comment: Yes, it does...

Comment: If duplicate rows are all the same you can just include them in the group-by.

Comment: Thank you, but just in case what if `b` does not match with `a` and I want to have first of it ordered by `a`

Comment: "Just in case"? You know you're data, don't state one thing and then state "that won't happen", @Aliaaa ... If you don't know you're requirements, I suggest you go and find them out *before* you post a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comments a value of `a` will only have one value of `b` so there is no "first" or "last" value, they are all the same. Therefore you could just `MIN`/`MAX` or `GROUP BY` `b` as well:

```sql
SELECT a,
       b,
       COUNT(a) AS [count]
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY a,
         b;

SELECT a,
       MAX(b) AS b,
       COUNT(a) AS [count]
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY a;
```

Answer (score 0):

I obtained the result you described doing this:

```
SELECT a, b, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM test
GROUP BY a, b;
```